# How to move a notion page from one account to another?

Tags: notion

In notion, how do I move a page from one account to another?

I know I could [follow the official instructions](https://www.notion.so/help/transfer-content-to-another-account), but this requires me to sign up for a free Team trial plan, and also requires me to have full access to the account I'm transferring the content to.

In my case, someone shared a page with me, and I'd like to transfer my page into a subpage of account B's page. Is there a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, one option is to [follow the official instructions](https://www.notion.so/help/transfer-content-to-another-account). However, there is a much simpler way if you only need to transfer a handful of pages.

Normally this can be done by selecting a bunch of blocks of text on the page, and then hitting ctrl+C to copy, and then pasting in the new account.

The one complication is tables, which it won't copy over by default if they're not displayed inline. Instead, it'll paste them as simple page links and only maintain their titles. To fix this:

1. Go to the container of the table hit "..." and choose "Turn into inline".
2. Add a placeholder node above or below the table (e.g. this could be a simple "Test" node with text).
3. Highlight all cells in the inline table and the placeholder node, then copy them.
4. Paste them into the new account's page.
   This will show a loading indicator showing that the entire table's contents is being migrated over.
5. The new title of the table will have a "(1)" after it, so you may want to rename it.
6. You can now convert it back to a table by choosing "Turn into page".